# how to show full image with overlay in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please tell me how to show `big` or `large` image on button click with overlay. I am making a image slider in which user click on `image` and it shows the full image with overlay. I tried like this

https://plnkr.co/edit/7AqAHSSPwZyj7cipXMrq?p=preview

```
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:9999;
    color:white;
}  

$(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  $('#next').click(function() {
    if (counter <  $('.imageBlock').length-1) {
      counter++;
      $('.imageBlock').hide();
      $('.imageBlock').eq(counter).show();
    }
  })
  $('#pre').click(function() {
    if (counter > 0) {
      counter--;
      $('.imageBlock').hide();
      $('.imageBlock').eq(counter).show();
    }
  })

  $('.imageBlock').click(function(){
    $('body html').addClass('overlay')
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where clicking the image - we take the `src`, and add it to a hidden div (`.overlay img`) and then show the div.

clicking the overlay hides it again.

Hope this is helpful

```js
   $('.thumb').on('click', function(){
  $('.overlay img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  $('.overlay').show();
});

$('.overlay').on('click', function(){
  $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

```css
.thumb {
  width: 250px;
}
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
    
    text-align: center;
}

.overlay img {
  width: 100%;
  border:5px solid #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="thumb" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1428094479093-8973a318bd76?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1001&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">

<div class="overlay"><span class="helper"></span><img src=""></div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/kbode1cx/

Comment: I tried your changes ..it works but why it full image scrolling https://plnkr.co/edit/7AqAHSSPwZyj7cipXMrq?p=preview

Comment: large image should display on centre

Comment: I have edited my answer to center the image. If this is helpful to you please mark as answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library, you can use [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) that does everything you need.

If you don't want to use a library, you can do that in your code (last jQuery event of your JS file) :

```
$('.imageBlock').click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('overlay');
    $('.imageBlock').eq(counter).find('.large img').toggle();
})
```

Comment: i don't want to use any library

Answer (score 0):

For starters `$('body html').addClass('overlay')` doesn't work, because that selects an `html` element inside a `body` element.. which doesn't exist.

I think you meant to target either class (to make it cross-browser):

`$('body,html')`

You could toggle the class:

`$('body,html').toggleClass('overlay')`

Then adjust your css. Probably something like this:

```
.overlay .imageBlock .small img {
display: none;
}
.overlay .imageBlock .large img {
display: block;
}
```

BTW, if you only need the `.small` and `.large` wrappers with img just for the overlay feature, then you're making things harder than needed...

Comment: pls share plunker